# "Invalid result returned from the software lookup service"

Tags: macos, cordova, app-store-connect, xcode-organizer

I am in the process of submitting an Mac OS X App. 
This App is created with [PhoneGap mac](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mac). The status in iTunes Connect is: `Waiting For Upload`.

When I try to upload through Organizer Xcode (Version 3.2.6) or through Application loader (Version 1.3), I get `Invalid result returned from the software lookup service`?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try creating a compressed zip file of the app that you want to submit to the store and use Application Loader on that.  Maybe it's just a temporary hic-cup, too.

Answer (score 0):

This problem most often occurs when you have no applications that are "Waiting for Upload".

There used to be an error something more like "No valid application profiles found", but they appear to have changed some functionality on the back end that caused this (unhelpful) error message.

To reach the "Waiting for Upload state":

- Log into iTunes Connect
- Navigate to Manage Your Applications

If the application that you want to upload is in the "Waiting for Upload" state, you are ready to go (*not*  the "Prepare for Upload" state). If this is the current state, you need to:

- Go into the details page for your application
- Press "Ready to Upload Binary"
- Answer the questions about encryption in the following pages.

After this, your upload should work.